# Why is `printf("%s", "foo")` not being optimized to `fputs("foo", stdout)`?

Tags: c, printf, compiler-optimization, fputs

So both GCC and Clang are smart enough to optimize `printf("%s\n", "foo")` to `puts("foo")` ([GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/c7eh7aTz3), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/MYessWY1a)). That's good and all.

But when I run this function through [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
    printf("%s", "foo");
}
```

Neither GCC nor Clang optimize `printf("%s", "foo")` to `fputs("foo", stdout)`, which I believe should be identical (since `fputs` doesn't put the newline like `puts`) to the `printf` and faster.

x86-64 GCC 11.1 ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/TWEj8MW18)):

```
.LC0:
        .string "foo"
.LC1:
        .string "%s"
foo:
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     printf
```

x86-64 Clang 12.0.0 ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/7T4fn8h59)):

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        mov     edi, offset .L.str
        mov     esi, offset .L.str.1
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     printf                          # TAILCALL
.L.str:
        .asciz  "%s"

.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "foo"
```

Is there any reason specific reason for no optimization to `fputs`, or is the compiler not smart enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some very specific situations are optimized, like the one you showed, but it's very superficial, if you add something to your format string, even a space, it [immediately discards the `puts` and goes back to `printf`](https://godbolt.org/z/hWTqoW9vG).

I guess that there would be nothing to stop a more broad optimization, my speculation is that, since the performance gains are not that great, further adding more *special* cases was deemed as not being worth it.

In my speculation, the lack of `fputs` optimization would fall in that *not being worth it* category.

This old gcc [`printf` optimization document](http://www.ciselant.de/projects/gcc_printf/gcc_printf.html) sheds some light on these optimizations, I doubt that it would much different today.

Specifically:

> #### 2.3 `%s\n`
>
> *A printf call with the format string `%s\n` [line 4679-4687] is converted to a `puts()` call.*
>
> ```
>  printf("%s\n", "hello world"); // converted to puts("hello world");
> ```

> #### 2.8 The string not ending with `\n`
>
> *No optimization if the string is not ending with `\n` [line 4721-4739].*

> #### 2.9 The string ending with `\n`
>
> *A `printf` call with a simple format string ending with `\n` [line 4721-4739] is converted to a `puts()` call.*
>
> ```
>  printf("hello world\n"); // converted to puts("hello world");
> ```

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that's fair enough. It doesn't *seem* too hard to implement something like that with the slightly modified code used to handle optimization to `puts` but I can't really say, I don't know much at all about how compilers see and optimize code, so eh :/

Comment: Just took a quick peek, point 2.8 seemed a bit interesting too. _"No optimization if the string is not ending with `\n`."_ Could maybe be a reason too, though this isn't followed with the optimization of `printf("%c", 'a')` so I feel that could be the same with `fputs`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 yes, and 2.9, I was adding them to the answer.